# Docker exiting the node app due to inactivity despite --restart=always

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker container running a node app on AWS with the following command

sudo docker run --restart always --network='host' image-name

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.19.0-alpine3.14

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "node","app.js"]
```

I have set the restart policy to always, but still when the container is exiting due to the node error “The client disconnected due to inactivity”, it is not restarting and the web-app is not loading after that. I have to restart the container manually.

Docker Inspect Status After Exiting:

```
"State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 1,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2022-04-03T12:02:21.533507861Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2022-04-03T20:06:36.98130893Z"
    },

"HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
```

Comment: Did your container run successfully or is it failing even during the run? restart policy will be applied once your container run successfully at least for some seconds

Comment: Yes, it's working fine after the run. Status- Up About an hour.